# How to setup automatic type hinting or stub generation for a python module with dynamically created class instances from parameter file/list

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

Say you have a module that does something like this:

```
# module/silly.py
from typing import Dict
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Tapanga:
    yodel: int

# Import from file or just a list in this module file
_defaults = {"Tap2": 2, "Uncle": 99, "Phish": 88}

def _define_global_instances()->Dict[str, Tapanga]:
    return {k: Tapanga(v) for k,v in _defaults.items()}
```

```
# module/__init__.py

from .silly import _define_global_instances


globals().update(_define_global_instances())
```

Then with the simple script:

```
import mod


print(mod.Tap2) # [Pyright reportGeneralTypeIssues] [E] "Tap2" is not a known member of module
```

Is there any way to automate the the type hinting of these class instances so that auto-completion will work?

If there is no other way -- Generating stubs is fine if that's the only option as long as the stubs are rebuilt on package install and not a complicated CI driven process. hotswapping the files where these types are generated is common, so regenerating the stubs must be fast/easy.

Edit0: Also wanted to say that it's also okay if the solution is to move away from the `globals().update` style shown below.